# Add Comment on top of existing comment (sendkeys behaviour)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that simply enters a comment in a cell. Linked with a hotkey as we use a lot of comments in a specific group file.

**The expected outcome:**

1. add a comment, enter date
2. if there already is a comment in the cell - add a new comment **above** (also with date)

**Issue:** 
The macro below does everything right, except the sendkeys at the very end. If I enter manually the combination: `Ctrl+Home`, then `End` I get exectly where I want in the added comment. 
On a comment that writes above the existing comment, I want to be exactly at the end of the date on the top line. As of now, everything works fine, except the curser still end at the bottom

**Question:** 
How do I get the vba inside a comment to behave like keys `Ctrl+Home`, then `End`

(**tldr:** Sendkeys in code does not work inside a comment)

```
    Option Explicit

Sub RPF_Comment()

Dim datum As String, old As String

datum = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ": "
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly

On Error GoTo Commentexists

ActiveCell.AddComment ("")
ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = True
ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.Select

With Selection
  .Font.Name = "Arial"
  .Font.Size = 8
  .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
  .Text = datum
End With
Exit Sub

Commentexists:
On Error GoTo out
ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = True
ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.Select
old = Selection.Text

With Selection
  .Font.Name = "Arial"
  .Font.Size = 8
  .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
  .Text = datum & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & old
End With

SendKeys "^{HOME}"
SendKeys "{End}"
out:

End Sub
```

PS: I know ".select" is not nice. but on a sub this long, 1 select is ok :)

Comment: 1 select is not ok if it's not needed... `Dim activeShape As Shape`; `Set activeShape = ActiveCell.Comment.Shape`, and then `With activeShape` and `old = activeShape.Text`. That said I don't understand why you need to position the caret inside the comment text, since that's the last thing you're (attempting) doing and by then the comment text has already been updated/rewritten.

Comment: Try getting the `.TextFrame2` of the comment shape (may need an explicit cast from `TextFrame`), it should have a `TextRange` property that's a `TextRange2` object, which has an `InsertBefore` method - does that method place the caret where you want it?

Comment: Hi Mathieu, Thanks a lot for your input. Unfortunately I did not get it to work, I'm not sure how to define the `.textframe2` that would allow me to use the `insertbefore` method